# Axios goes into an infinite loop when the output is accessed from a top-level property in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code. If I access the output stored in the top-level property , then Axios goes into an infinite loop. If I remove `jsonData` from HTML, then Axios makes 5 requests, as expected.

How do I fix the infinite loop issue and still be able to access the output from the top level property?

```js
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-for="n in 5" :call-api="getSingleItem(n)">
            {{ jsonData }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const { createApp } = Vue
        createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    jsonData: []
                }
            },
            methods: {
                async getSingleItem(itemId) {

                    await axios
                        .get('https://dummyjson.com/users/' + itemId)
                        .then((response) => {
                            output = response.data;
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error)
                        })

                    let entryExists = _.find(this.jsonData, { 'itemId': itemId });

                    if (!entryExists) {
                        this.jsonData.push({
                            'itemId': itemId,
                            'data': output
                        });
                    } else {
                        let index = _.findIndex(this.jsonData, { 'itemId': itemId });
                        this.jsonData.splice(index, 1,
                            {
                                'itemId': itemId,
                                'data': output
                            }
                        )
                    }
                },
            }

        }).mount('#app')

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You should never do getSingleItem() in a template. It causes side effects which are triggered on each rerender

Comment: I see. And what would the solution look like?

Comment: Call it in once in lifecycle hook

Comment: Would you please post the full code solution for a beginner like me? :)

Comment: `createApp({ mounted() { [...Array(5).keys().map(k => k + 1)].forEach(this.getSingleItem) }})`.